# How to simplify context free grammar?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

How to simplify this context-free grammar into a similar one with no unit productions and no useless symbols?

$$
S \to ABA \\ A \to aAA \mid aBC \mid bB \\ B \to A \mid bB \mid Cb \\ C \to CC \mid cC 
$$

Can the simplification result in this CFG?

$$
S \to ABA \\ A \to aAA \\ A \to Bb \\ B \to b
$$

Comment: The first grammar can produce a $c$…

Answer (score 0):

The context free language at the top seems to be empty, as there always will be a variable at any time while trying to derive a word! (this is because every transition is from a variable to some a few letters and at least one variable)